# Fixed table header with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, sticky

I'm having a conflict because my header is only fixed when I take the div with the table-responsive class, but I need it to have the table overflow.
Can someone help me?

1. With the table-responsive class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped w-auto">
            <thead class="bg-light sticky-top">
                <tr>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

2. Without table-responsive class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped w-auto">
            <thead class="bg-light sticky-top">
                <tr>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                    <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Important:** I need the table-responsive class to have the table overflow when needed.

Answer (score 6):

`table-responsive` features `overflow: auto;`, hence, why your header is not staying sticky.

> "A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position
> value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its
> containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to
> value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it
> scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting
> the opposite edge of its containing block."

~ [position: - CSS - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

I would try this setup as an alternative. It doesn't have the problematic `table-responsive` class. However, the header is sticky and the table is still responsive as it was with the `responsive` class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="position-relative">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead class="bg-light sticky-top top-0">
        <tr>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
          <th>header</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: With that I still can't get the expected result, because the table exceeds the size of the screen.

[Image](https://prnt.sc/zx0y8om-jl6_)

Comment: @BryanSantos tables are hardly responsive. Even with the table-responsive class you will have an overflow. The only way you could get it to fit the screen without overflow would set up a `calc` width for each  `tr` and `td`. Or perhaps, with a media query.

Comment: @BryanSantos In short, the quote in my solution says you cannot use `sticky-top` while having `overflow: auto;` on the parent div. Which is what `table-responsive` does. So with this setup, the default overflow in the `body` will have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

table-responsive makes the table container to be scrollable horizontally and it will become the nearest ancestor that has scrolling mechanism for the sticky header, and according to the documentation[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), an element with position sticky will only sticks to the nearest ancestor with scrolling mechanism, in this case it would be the table container rather than the window as we wanted.